# Use a Dialog instead an option menu on ICS

Tags: android, menu, custom-component, optionmenu

I want to use a dialog as option menu in my application, the problem is I've understood that smartphones without buttons only show the menu button if the activity have an action menu implemented.
How can I show a Dialog instead a Menu without lost the Menu button on ICS?

Thanks a lot! Regards from Spain!

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer [here](http://techblog.rokoder.com/android-missing-menu-button/). In short, you just decrease the target sdk version, and then the menu button will appear on all ICS devices. And then you just use this to detect the click:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event ) {
    if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
        //do you thing here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keycode,event); 
}
```